# Directadmin и ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ispmanager, ubuntu

Есть ли альтернативная морда под Ubuntu или возможность завести его.

Answer (score 2):

[`Webmin`](http://www.webmin.com/) есть. Не совсем то, но функции те же.

Но и [`DirectAdmin`](http://www.directadmin.com/install.html) для `Debian/Ubuntu` есть.

Comment: знаю, но клиент хочет директ =(

Comment: Ну так есть же! Ссылку дал. В чём проблема? Покупать не хочет?

Comment: дык 12.04 убунта )

Comment: Да! В DA справился - говорят, не поддерживают! А жаль! Ну, тут либо шашечки, либо ехать. Похоже, вам придётся откатиться на Люсю - 10.04. Что для хорошего сервера - самое оно!На самом деле я тоже люблю всё новое, и на домашнем серваке у меня вообще 12.10 стоит. Но для работы предпочитаю что-то проверенное временем. У меня где-то сервак и на 2003-й венде есть! Я его пока не собираюсь менять. Если работает - то пусть работает!